# How is this happening? python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
my_list= [(0,1,2),(3,4,5),(6,7,8)]
for a,b,c in my_list:
    print(a)
    print(b)
    print(c)
my_list = a+b+c
print(my_list)
```

I run this and it comes as 21 for last i would just like to know how that comes thanks again!

Comment: What were you expecting? 6 + 7 + 8 is 21.

Comment: What have you done to understand what's happening?

Comment: To what value is `my_list` initialised?  Cannot determine what you are iterating over.

Comment: sorry while editing error

Answer (score 1):

In the last iteration a = 6, b = 7 and c = 8, hence it is giving you 21.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is iterating through your array, and unpacking the tuple into a,b,c.

The last tuple is (6,7,8) and when it maps to (a,b,c) it is unpacked to a=6, b=6, c=8.

What you call my_list will not be a list, but the sum of a,b and c.